# Why my NSMutableArray can't be saved

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im trying to save my nsmutablearray to disk,
array looks:

```
       self.tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dawdw" andImage:@"dwddw" andDescription:@"dawdw" andTypes:@"dawwd dawwd" andforWho:@"dwaadw"],
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"Kabanos" andImage:@"spodwwdwdrt.jpg" andDescription:@"dwdw" andTypes:@"dwdw dww" andforWho:@"dawwd"],
                          [[Cell alloc] initWithName:@"dwwd" andImage:@"dwwd" andDescription:@"dwwd" andTypes:@"wdwd daww" andforWho:@"dadawwa"],nil];


//execution
[self writeToPlist:@"fav.txt" withData:self.tableData];


- (void) writeToPlist: (NSString*)fileName withData:(NSMutableArray *)data
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [data writeToFile:finalPath atomically: YES];
}

//loading
- (NSMutableArray *) readFromPlist: (NSString *)fileName {
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *finalPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:finalPath];

    if (fileExists) {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:finalPath];
        return arr;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

//load
 self.tableData = [self readFromPlist:@"fav.txt"];
```

and sadly finally tableData is empty, i tried few ways to save nsmutablearray but i can't figure out how to.

Comment: Read the docs for `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:`. See what it says about the types of objects you can save.

Comment: so any other idea to save&read nsmutablearray?

Comment: What you are doing is just fine for saving and reading an array. The problem is the data in the array. Either change the array data so it is savable or do some searching on saving arrays containing custom objects.

Comment: I couldnt find anything to save nsmutablearray, could you show any example?

Comment: Really? What about [these results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+save+array+custom+objects)?

Comment: you should implement `NSCoding` protocol in your `Cell` class to be able to save those objects to disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your mutable array contains custom objects, the OS will not know how to encode and decode them.
The custom class can be encoded and decoded by addding the following functions to your class.
Make sure the class conforms to **NSCoding**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    self.var1 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"var1"];
    self.var2 = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"var2"];
    .. and so on
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.var1 forKey:@"var1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.var2 forKey:@"var2"];
}
```

Now to Archive -

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:<array of objects> toFile:@"/path/to/archive"];
```

To unarchive

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/path/to/archive"];
```

Hth

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If the array’s contents are all property list objects (**NSString**,
>   **NSData**, **NSArray**, or **NSDictionary** objects), the file written by this
>   method can be used to initialize a new array with the class method
>   arrayWithContentsOfFile: or the instance method
>   initWithContentsOfFile:. This method recursively validates that all
>   the contained objects are property list objects before writing out the
>   file, and returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects,
>   since the resultant file would not be a valid property list.

(emphasis mine)

You could make a method on your Cell class that turns it to/from `NSData` or any other property list object, put tha into the array and then save it.